# Photoshop-like navigator for website

Tags: plugins, jquery-plugins, hint

Are there any plugins or ideas about how to achieve a Photoshop-like navigator for a website? 
What I mean is that the website is much wider/longer than the viewport and the user shall see in a small panel which part of the website he currently sees.

Appreciate every hint.

Update: some keywords I found so far: navigation / overview pane, birdview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found jQuery.fracs which works perfectly for me: https://larsjung.de/jquery-fracs/

Comment: Another solution (but not free) is https://codecanyon.net/item/mgminimap-jquery-minimap-plugin/5698116?s_rank=1